# Stripe - Monthly Subscription with First Period Length

Tags: stripe-payments

We offer a **Pro Monthly Subscription** where the monthly rate is $50 but we require the first 2-months to be pre-paid upfront.

Or you could rephrase another way; the first month of a Subscription is paid and the second month is pre-paid.

With another payment processor (FastSpring) we could configure a **First Period Length** on Subscriptions. For example, a **Pro Monthly Subscription** is purchased but the **First Period Length** is set to `2-months`.

Here's a scenario:

1. Subscription is purchased on July 1st
2. First 2-months pre-paid on July 1st = $100
3. Next charge date is September 1st = $50
4. Charges ($50) continue monthly until Subscription is cancelled

We haven't found a clean way to accomplish the same **First Period Length** with Stripe.

Any idea how something similar could be configured with Stripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Product with two Pricing Plans and a scheduled change to the Subscription was a good fit for our scenario.

The first Pricing Plan (**Intro**) is configured with a 2-month term and $100 fee (2 * $50/month).

Second Pricing Plan is the regular monthly rate ($50/month).

When the Subscription is created the Intro plan starts on Day0 and a change is scheduled for 2-months to switch the Subscription to the regular Monthly pricing plan.

Here's the configuration in the Dashboard:

[image: Stripe Subscription with First Period Length]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a trial period and a one off-invoice. Here's the flow:

1. Create the subscription and set the trial period to 60 days: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_period_days
2. Create a one-off invoice to immediately charge for 2 months ($100): https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/one-off
3. After the 2 month trial period is over, the regular monthly subscription ($50 a month) will kick in

Comment: The trial period with an invoice works, although we did end up going with another solution where a scheduled pricing plan change was configured on the Subscription. I added as a separate answer in this thread.

Comment: Still would be a lot cleaner if Stripe included a **First Period Length** option on their Subscriptions.